# Visual Studio .exe file of bootstrp start downloading again and again after completing

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

[image]when i download community file from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/ it start downloading on the completing of downloading the downloading status change to verifying but then suddenly it start downloading same files again, and that continues.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to uninstall and install Visual Studio again?

If you need to install bootstrap you can do it on visual studio, you don't need to go on visual studio website.